# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find') When using Async/Await

Tags: javascript, mongodb, async-await

I learning how to use javascript to work with the mongodb database, but I keep getting an error when initializing cursor. In the injectDB function, customers is defined, but once getCustomers() is called, customers ends up being undefined. How do I fix this?

```
var customers

export default class CustomersDAO{
    static async injectDB(conn){
        if(customers){
            return
        }
        try {
            customers = await conn.db(process.env.NS).collection("Customers") 
            //console.log(customers)
        } catch(e){
            console.error(`Unable to establish a collection handle in CustomersDAO, ${e}`)
        }
        console.log(`customers in function: ${customers}`)
    }

    static async getCustomers(){
        let query = {first: "Yanely"}
        
        let cursor
        try {
            cursor = await customers.find(query)
        } catch(e){
            console.error(`Unable to issue find command, ${e}`)
            return {customersList: [], totalCustomers: 0}
        }
        console.log(cursor)
     }
}
```

injectDB is being called in my index.js file

```
MongoClient.connect(
    process.env.URI, {
        maxPoolSize: 50,
        wtimeoutMS: 2500,
        useNewUrlParser: true
    }
).catch(err => {
    console.error(err.stack)
    process.exit(1)
}).then(async client => {
    await CustomersDAO.injectDB(client)
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)
    })
})
```

while getCustomers is being called in my controller file

```
    static async apiGetCustomers(req, res, next){
        
        const {customersList, totalCustomers} = await CustomersDAO.getCustomers()
    
        let response = {
            customers: customersList,
            total: totalCustomers
        }
        res.json(response)
    }
}
```

I'm expecting for the customers variable to hold the connection made from the inject function, so I can use getCustomers() to retrieve the data from the db.

Comment: that means that `customers` at `await customers.find(query)` is `undefined`

Comment: but why is that so? How do I make it defined since I'm defining it when injectDB is called?

Comment: perhaps `apiGetCustomers` is called before `injectDB` is called - though, that doesn't look likely